# Is there a multi-world bukkit-plugin with per-world(-group) inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I set up my bukkit server to run multiple worlds. However, one of them is supposed to be a creative one (i.e. `give` etc allowed), another one is survival based and no cheating allowed. Currently the inventory stays the same when travelling from one world to another, which kind of defies the purpose. Is there a plugin for bukkit to have an individual inventory for each world or even better for different world-groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you should get [Multiverse-core](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-core/) and [Multiverse-Inventoriess](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-inventories/) and [Multiverse-Portals](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-portals/)

It's an awesome plugin set to get you more worlds and you don't need to go into the config files you just type /mv create  and in the creative world you can do /mvm set gamemode creative

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: Good point, I switched to it a while ago but forgot to mention it here, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is! You can use [Default Commands](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/6847/), which brings multi-world support with a join-command to get to the other worlds and a really huge per-world configuration-file. You can set whether the world should be a creative-world or not, or if there should be a separate inventory for a world.

If this plugin is too extensive for your needs, you may use [MultiInv](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/4742/) which lets you also have separate inventories.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think MultiInv perfectly serves my needs, but I'll check Default Commands as well

Comment: Although I have both plugins installed on my server, I prefer MultiInv because of its simplicity. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered already and good suggestions have been made, but from my experience with Multiverse, inventories and creative vs survival worlds, I ended up switching my server to Spigot and setting up Bungeecord, and running my creative and survival servers as 2 separate servers instead of through Multiverse.

Why you might ask? I had been burned one too many times by players finding ways to exploit creative to survival inventory transfers. Several times with Multiverse-Portals players were able to glitch their inventories from creative into the survival world by spamming the items in and out of their toolbar very quickly as they went through the portal. Or they used minecart chests and some clever hacks like freecam. Other exploits have included teleporting, enderchests, and economy plugins.

I felt like the safest bet in order to keep creative out of my survival world was 2 server instances. I know multiverse-inventories has been fixed up a lot since then, but new exploits in minecraft are always just a day away.

Comment: Fortunately my "server" only consists of my (honest) wife and me, but (if you add some links) this answer might still help others, thanks!